# Why do I get the wrong IMAP Server?

Tags: python, email, smtp, imap

I'm trying to get the IMAP Server from an E-Mail address with Python

```
hostname = dns.resolver.query(username.split('@')[1], 'MX')[0].to_text().split(' ')[-1]
```

but I get the SMTP Server and even the wrong one

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The IMAP server is not exposed as a dns entry type directly. See [Is there a standard DNS record to indicate the IMAP server for a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/814715/is-there-a-standard-dns-record-to-indicate-the-imap-server-for-a-domain). The MX entry is the receiving SMTP server for the domain.

Comment: I will try it like Thunderbird thanks